# Prometheus: Add a label based on other labels

Tags: prometheus, amazon-ecs

I've set up Prometheus to use the file sd from [prometheus-ecs-discovery](https://github.com/teralytics/prometheus-ecs-discovery):

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: ecs
  file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - /prometheus/ecs_file_sd.yml
```

This adds among other labels the task arn as a label:

```
container_label_com_amazonaws_ecs_task_arn=
"arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:xxxxxx:task/2c1655cd-36b7-4db9-4326-ee90537b6271"
```

In grafana, I'd like to use the task ID (`2c1655cd-36b7-4db9-4326-ee90537b6271` in my example) as the legend for most of my stats, which can be extracted from the task arn. Can I somehow **add** a new label?

Answer (score 2):

This can be acheived using a [relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config). This will allow you to create a new target label from a source label.

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: ecs
  file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - /prometheus/ecs_file_sd.yml
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [container_label_com_amazonaws_ecs_task_arn]
      regex: '.*\/(.*)'
      replacement: '${1}'
      target_label: task_id
```

The above will create a new label named `task_id` with value being the part after the `/` of the `container_label_com_amazonaws_ecs_task_arn` label.

Comment: could you describe why you use a `relabel_config` instead of a `metric_relabel_config`? I found this blog post which describes `relabel` as pre-scrape and `metric` as post scrape, pre-ingest. https://www.robustperception.io/relabel_configs-vs-metric_relabel_configs

Why are these names so non-indicative of their actual purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't think it solves the problem for the OP, I came across this question as the title is similar to what I was stuck on.

I had labels, eg:
`label_1="blue"` and `label_2="green"`
and I wanted to add a new label (`label_3`), using the value of `label_2` with a regex match on `label_1`.

This could be achieved using `relabel_configs` with multiple `source_labels` https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config

```
- source_labels: [label_1, label_2]
  separator: ';'
  target_label: label_3
  regex: "blue;(.+)"
  replacement: '${2}'
  action: replace
```

Comment: Can we use something like this to add new labels to the scraped data too ? like add env: 'dev' as a label ?

Comment: @im_bhatman, Prometheus doesn't provide functionality for adding labels to already stored data. But it provides [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function, which can be used for adding new labels based on other labels during querying. For example, `label_replace({job="ecs"}, "task_id", "$1", "container_label_com_amazonaws_ecs_task_arn", "[^/]+/(.+)")` would extract `task_id` part from `container_label_com_amazonaws_ecs_task_arn` label and put it into `task_id` label at query time.